# API snapchat get firstname+lastname

Tags: java, php, html

I want to create a program that gets first name and last name of Snapchat username.

[image]

For example, if I type username `kxo` it will display its name: **Kelsey W** if it's possible to create list.txt and we add more usernames and the program will display their first name and last name.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. If you have any specific code issues, please let us know! We're not here to write code, an entire platform or finding libraries/APIs for you, so your question is too broad and will likely get closed.